# Using subclasses with RxJava Observable

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, rx-java

I'm facing an error with the following code:

```
interface A1 {
    val string: String
}

data class A2(override var string: String = "") : A1

interface Test {
    fun f(): Observable<List<A1>>
}

fun func(): Observable<List<A2>> = return ...

class TestImpl : Test{
    override fun f(): Observable<List<A1>> = func()
}
```

There's a type mismatch in the last line of code. How do I change this to have the correct declaration, if at all possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could genericise your interface as follows:

```
interface Test<T: A1> {
    fun f(): Observable<List<T>>
}
```

Then implement it as follows:

```
class TestImpl : Test<A2> {
    override fun f(): Observable<List<A2>> = func()
}
```

Comment: I tried with `out List`, but it still doesn't work. The warning I get for the `out` is `projection is redundant the corresponding type parameter of list has the same variance`

Comment: But if I do use `List` instead of `MutableList`, and remove `Observable`, it works. Actually, `List` is all I need, since I only need to read the values. I'll update the question to reflect that. Nevertheless, `Observable` is still needed, and the problem remains.

Comment: Have changed my answer now to fit with the updated question.